# send file from jboss 7 in alfresco

Tags: java, jboss, alfresco

I want to send file from my application to alfresco

I work in jboss 7

but when I test my application and when I test the attachement  I have this error :

```
10:25:33,684 INFO  [org.directwebremoting.log.accessLog] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-5) Method execution failed: : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xml.security.transforms.Transform.init()V
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig.staticInit(WSSConfig.java:244) [wss4j-1.5.4-patched.jar:]
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig.<init>(WSSConfig.java:256) [wss4j-1.5.4-patched.jar:]
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig.getNewInstance(WSSConfig.java:265) [wss4j-1.5.4-patched.jar:]
    at org.apache.ws.security.handler.WSHandler.doSenderAction(WSHandler.java:89) [wss4j-1.5.4-patched.jar:]
    at org.apache.ws.axis.security.WSDoAllSender.invoke(WSDoAllSender.java:170) [wss4j-1.5.4-patched.jar:]
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32) [axis-1.4.jar:]
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118) [axis-1.4.jar:]
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83) [axis-1.4.jar:]
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:127) [axis-1.4.jar:]
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784) [axis-1.4.jar:]
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767) [axis-1.4.jar:]
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443) [axis-1.4.jar:]
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366) [axis-1.4.jar:]
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812) [axis-1.4.jar:]
```

I use in my application this jars :

alfresco-web-service-client-4.0.d.jar , axis-1.4.jar,axis-saaj-1.2.jar,wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar,wss4j-1.5.4-patched.jar

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are missing `xmlsec-1.4.2.jar`, or some other version.

If this doesn't help, it is possible that you have class conflicts, so check

> META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml

and exclude `org.apache.xml.security` with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.1">
    <ear-subdeployments-isolated>true</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="deployment.javaee.api" />
        </dependencies>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="javaee.api" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
    <module name="deployment.javaee.api">
        <dependencies>
            <module name="javaee.api" export="true">
                <imports>
                    <exclude path="org/apache/xml/security/**" />
                </imports>
            </module>
        </dependencies>
    </module>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but I have put this jar (xmlsec-1.4.1.jar) in my application, I think that is problem of version or a conflict of jar between jar of jboss and jar of application

Comment: when I search under jboss 7 I didn't find jboss-deployment-structure.xml  I find jboss-cli under :  jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin

Comment: It should be created in your package. Create it inside META-INF. I've posted the structure for it.